# Accept (Shift + Return) But Not (Return)

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a RichTextBox in a WPF Application in which I wish to accept Shift + Return but not Return. How might I do this in my XAML.

When I place the

```
AcceptsReturn="True"
```

It blocks all Return action (as I would expect from the name)

So is there a way to handle Return conditionally in XAML?

Comment: You have to do that in code behind.

Comment: That's what I figured, but I thought it worth asking because I wasn't sure.